# Is Malayappa Swamy Vigraha Swambhu/Self Manifested

Tags: vishnu, venkateshwara, tirupati

[Swayambhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swayambhu) Vigraha means incarnated figure or an idol which has no human involvement in its creation, generally such Idols/figures are more important and considered to be more sacred than man-made idols/figures. The [Mulavar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moolavar) or the main deity in [Venkateshwara Swamy Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara_Temple,_Tirumala) is one of the Swayambhu idols.

The [Utsava Murty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uthsavar) in Tirumala Tirupati Temple is known as [Malayappa Swamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayappa_swami), all the sevas like Arjita Vasantaotsavam, Sahasra Deepa Mala etc., are performed to Malayappa Swamy.

Is Malayappa Swamy self-manifested? What about Sri Devi and Bhu Devi Vigraha with swamy?

Comment: Yes, Malayappa Swami is Swayambhu.  He appeared in a place in the seven hills called Malayappan Konai: http://www.adiyenramanujadasan.org/tirumala/glories/tpstvs6.html

Comment: Yes. He spoke about his presence to the devotees at the time and ordered them to locate him.

Comment: Maybe you got the doubt due to the man made external ornate appearance of the Utsavamurthy? For a procession such presentation is appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [Malayappa Swami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayappa_swami) is swayambhu or self manifest. Malayappa swami is also known as [Utsava Beram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deities_in_Tirumala_Venkateswara_Temple#Utsava_Beram) because he is the processional deity of Tirumala.

Malayappa swamy was discovered in a hill which is now named as Malayappa kona. Th legend goes like this.

> On one occasion, there was a time when fore broke out during Brahmotsavam in Tirumala. The reason was not known to the priests and the devotees didn't know the reason for this. After sincere prayers were performed, Lord spoke through a person. He said that the times had changed and ordered that [Ugra Srinivasa Murti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugra_Srinivasa) should be no longer used as processional deity, and in the mountains another murti will be found. He ordered to use that murti only for this purpose(for Brahmotsavam, processions). After searching in hillside, new processional deity along with his consorts was found.

This happened in the 14<sup>th</sup> century A.D. This is evident from the inscription by the King Ranganatha Yadavaraya from 1339 A.D. The original name of this murti is Malay Kuniya Ninra Perumal (Lord stood on the hill which bowed low to Him).

Sources:

1. [The Tirumala Temple by Dr.Ramesan](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.162281/2015.162281.The-Tirumala-Temple_djvu.txt)
2. [Lord of Vengadam](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rntPBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=malayappa++idol+history&source=bl&ots=tTtbY3MfqP&sig=3V8rhXiNpPpxOa7uaQ3pKhC4pzY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHw_Svv6XXAhUJlJQKHeIwCJ4Q6AEIXzAM#v=onepage&q=) [See Page 144, 145,146].

Comment: Do you know Telugu or Sanskrit name of Malayappa Swami?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Malayappa Swami is generally known as Utsava Muti only. There is no Sanskrit name. The original was Malay Kuniya Ninra Perumal. This gradually changed to Malayappa. Telugu people also use Malayappa. The name became famous like that.